# Is there a game that works on one computer but with four players?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Is there a game for Ubuntu where four players can play at once?

We have four game controllers and people with the age of 5 up to 50.

The game should be simple: 2-D, not 3-D.

It can be commercial software, too.

Comment: The question was closed as "too broad". I don't think this fits. Please look at the detailed requirements. The problem is: Nobody knows a game which fits the requirements.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the gaming stack, or software recommendations site.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for super tux kart! It's like mario kart but with a Linux feel to it :)
It's a 3D game but it has simple graphics and it's done in a playful way.

It's available in the [software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/supertuxkart/) or from [sourceforge.](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/Downloads#header_win)

As you can see below, it works well with a 4-way split screen. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my eyes and head hurt after playing it for some minutes. Somehow I have more fun playing 2D games like in the old days with my C64. Still looking for a game for several players....

Comment: I updated the question: I search for a 2-D, not 3-D game now.

Comment: @guettli it's still not suited for this site, as this questions has already been closed for too broad, because the answer is depended on an opinion...

Comment: @guettli I would just google the topic instead of asking here anyways,  or searching the software center...